# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

An admin account for ssrs password was changed so the encryption key had a problem and now no longer getting encryption error. However now when I try to access the reports I am prompted again for creds to the datasource. The creds I use to access the report doesn't work for the datasource. 
I get
'An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot create a connection to data source 'xxxxx'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

If I try to do anything like delete a folder or edit the datasource I get 'Could not connec to the server. Please check your network settings and tray again later.

Comment: Using sql server 2016

Answer (score 2):

To fix:

1. Right click on the report project and select "Properties".
2. In left panel, select "Configuration Properties" -> "General"
3. In right panel, expand "Deployment".  Set "OverwriteDataSource" to TRUE.

Close dialog and deployed report again.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I Had the issue since 3 days and i figured it out.

I just had to go to the Data Sources in your SSRS web portal (http://instancename/path/browse). Update it by adding your connection string and credentials (I chose as the user viewing the report to make it work).

And my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was chrome and using report manager. The creds were cache/saved and when in chrome could not make any changes, deletions or adds. Went into firefox that I never used to connect to report manager and I allowed me to create a new shared datasource and point the reports to them. After that the issue gone.